# view setBackgroundColor does not call viewdidload in Xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, ios6, xcode4.5

I just upgraded to Xcode4.5. When I ran the unit tests, I realised that [view setbackgroundcolor] does not call [viewdidload].

Did anyone had the same issue?

Comment: Why should setting the background color of a UIView trigger the viewDidLoad method?

Comment: Well, I inherited somecode from someoneelse. The comment explicitly mentioned that. I did run the test in xcode 4.4 viewdidload gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is some **undocumented** behavior which you should not rely upon, because it (will break your code one day) *just broke your code*...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using iOS6?

> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html
>
> Prior to iOS 6, when a low-memory warning occurred, the UIViewController class purged its >views if it knew it could reload or recreate them again later. If this happens, it also calls >the viewWillUnload and viewDidUnload methods to give your code a chance to relinquish >ownership of any objects that are associated with your view hierarchy, including objects >loaded from the nib file, objects created in your viewDidLoad method, and objects created >lazily at runtime and added to the view hierarchy. On iOS 6, views are never purged and these >methods are never called. If your view controller needs to perform specific tasks when memory >is low, it should override the didReceiveMemoryWarning method.